# How to transform a Kafka Stream event and send it to another topic only if could be transformed

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to build a simple Kafka stream that tries to transform events based on some conditions. If the event can be transformed, the transformed event goes into a different topic. If the event cannot be transformed, it is stored again in the same topic for a future try.

Let's say I have this:

```
case class Foo(a: String, b: String, c: Boolean)

def translate(value: String): Option[Foo] = {
  // ...
  // Returns an Option of Foo
}
```

So I would need to have something like this:

```
val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()

builder
  .stream(topic)
  .map[String, String]((key, value) => translate(value))
  // If translate(value) is Some(value) send the value to a topic
  // Otherwise, send the original value (without being transformed) to the same topic
```

I'm totally stuck with this issue. The nearest thing I've come across is try to create a structure with a boolean that tells me if the event can be transformed or not, and then create different streams with a `.branch`. For instance, something like this:

```
def translate(value: String): (Boolean, Option[CPCTTMDataTransformed]) = {
  val eventTransformed = transform(value)
  eventTransformed match {
    case Some(value) => (true, Option(value))
    case None => (false, None)
  }
}
```

And then try to do something like this:

```
builder
  .stream(topic)
  .map[String, (Boolean, Option[Foo])]((key, value) => translate(value))
  .branch(
    (_, element) => element._1,
  )
  .foreach {
    // Send the "true" to one topic and in the "false", send the original message to the original topic 
  }
```

But of course I would need to have the original event to send it to the topic.

I've though about more complicated structures, but in the end I always come back to the problem of branching the stream based on a `Some`-`None` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the Processor API. You have one `Processor` that does the translation, and if the translations is successful you `context.forward(To.child("translated"))` otherwise you `context.forward(To.child("retry"))`.

You plug your `Topology` together manually:

```java
Topology topology = new Topology();
topology.addSource("source", topic);
topology.addProcessor("translator", () -> new TranslateProcessor(), "source");
topology.addSink("translated", resultTopic, "translator");
topology.addSink("retry", topic, "translator");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Matthias! I didn't know that API, I will look into it.

Comment: In the end, I've used the Processor API to create a KeyValue store where I save the events that cannot be translated. I've programmed the `punctuate` method to periodically check if the translation can be done, and if so, translate it and send it to the "translated" topic. My understanding is that, this way, we don't need the "retry" topic. Does it sound like a nice approach to you?

Comment: Sound totally reasonably :)